# Python regex - match names with legal forms

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match names and legal forms.
At the moment i have this:

```py
[a-zA-Z]*\,\s*[[A-Z]\.]*
```

I need to match with these examples:

- Bank, A.
- Bank, A.B.
- Bank, A.B.C.
- Bank, A.B.C.D.
- BANK, A.
- BANK, A.B.
- ...etc (BANK, A. ... X.)

At the moment I am able to match only with "Bank, A." and "BANK, A.".

How to to change the regex so it matches also the following legal term abbreviations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could repeat the A-Z part followed by a dot 1+ times and match an optional A-Z at the end to also match A.B

```
^[a-zA-Z]+,\s(?:[A-Z]\.)+[A-Z]?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ a-zA-Z
- `,\s` Match a comma and a whitespace character
- `(?:` [Non capturing group](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap)

  - `[A-Z]\.` Match A-Z and a dot
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times to match `A.` or `A.B.`
- `[A-Z]?` Match optional A-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uLHr3l/1)

Or using a word boundary `\b` at the start and assert non a non whitespace `(?!\S)` at the end:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+,\s(?:[A-Z]\.)+[A-Z]?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/knyKy8/1)

Comment: @TambetTamm That is a [non capturing group](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) `(?:[A-Z]\.)+`which you can repeat as a whole matching a char A-Z followed by a dot. If you repeat the character class and you place the dot in it `[A-Z.]+` it could also match only dots

Comment: Much more defensive +1

Answer (score 2):

If this pattern is always the same you can try

`\w+\,\s[A-Z\.]+`

See this at work at: https://regex101.com/r/cw0KW3/1